# How to obtain email address with window authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email, windows-authentication

I am designing a web application using the ASP.net MVC framework.  I would like to use Windows Authentication and do Role Checks using the Role Manager SQLRoleProvider.

How can I determine the email address of the current logged on user?  Is this even possible?

The application will be deployed in a multi-domain intranet, if that matters (which I assume it does).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look up the user's properties in Active Directory. Here is a great article that explains how to do that using System.DirectoryServices and C#:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6778/How-to-get-User-Data-from-the-Active-Directory

Comment: **This link is no longer valid. Often it is suggested to not use links for the very reason. Please post example code. (for @Raiden Flyboy)

Answer (score 13):

Here is a sample from some code:

```
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher();    
searcher.Filter = string.Format("sAMAccountName={0}", _name);    
SearchResult user = searcher.FindOne();    
string emailAddr = user.Properties["mail"][0].ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks for this. :)

Answer (score 0):

In MVC5 application give the action as given below

```
  public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string name = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
            ViewBag.Name = name;
            ViewBag.Email = uEmail(User.Identity.Name.Replace(@"YOURDOMAIN\", ""));
            return View();
        }
```

Change the **YOURDOMAIN** to your domain name. And give the uEmail function as given below. Also add the reference to using **System.Security.Principal** and **using System.DirectoryServices**.

```
private string uEmail(string uid)
        {
            DirectorySearcher dirSearcher = new DirectorySearcher();
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(dirSearcher.SearchRoot.Path);
            dirSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectcategory=person)(mail=" + uid + "*))";

            SearchResult srEmail = dirSearcher.FindOne();

            string propName = "mail";
            ResultPropertyValueCollection valColl = srEmail.Properties[propName];
            try
            {
                return valColl[0].ToString();
            }
            catch
            {
                return "";
            }

        }
```

Comment: I think the user name not equal to email account even you remove the domain

Comment: @MichaelMao I think he is not removing the domain only, at the same time invoking the 'uEmail' method, where it bring the email address from the AD

Comment: Pretty sure that `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` doesn't give you the identity of the client, but the user hosting the website...