# Windows Authentication User.Identity.Name to email address

Tags: c#, active-directory, windows-authentication

I have already tried to use [How to obtain email address with window authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638644/how-to-obtain-email-address-with-window-authentication), but a question remains:

I know how to ask for email address for John Smith, but what I get as authentication name is like INTRA\\JohnSmith3 or DEP21\\JohnSmith

How can I map INTRA\\JohnSmith3 or DEP21\\JohnSmith to the correct John Smith in AD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get from Windows Authentication is the SAM Account Name. You need to look this up in Active Directory.

You can query Active Directory for users like this:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=JohnSmith3))
```

In code:

```
string filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)"
     + "(objectClass=user)"
     + "(sAMAccountName=" + samAccountName + "))";
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(myLdapConnection);
search.Filter = filter;
SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
DirectoryEntry de = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
```

Comment: If I omit the domain, aren't DEP21\\JohnSmith and HQ\\JohnSmith pointing to the same AD entry?

Comment: The SAM Account Name does not include the domain. You can do a search where you don't do a `FindOne()` but a `FindAll()` and then filter the results on domain. To see how to find the domain of a given user, check out this other question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249139/c-sharp-active-directory-get-domain-name-of-user

Comment: So best would be to extract the domain name from the User.Identity.Name and use it to connect to the AD for that domain?